# Was Joseph Gordon-Levitt's character, John Blake based on any comic book characters?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

Joseph Gordon-Levitt plays 'hot-headed' police officer John Blake in The Dark Knight Rises.

**What, if any, comic book characters is this character based on?**

Comment: Related: [Does Joseph Gordon-Levitt's character in The Dark Knight Rises have a comic-book counterpart?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/113839/49)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Having just watched the movie earlier today, I think John Blake's character draws together bits & pieces from the three main Robins - Dick Grayson, Jason Todd, and Tim Drake.

The cop part comes from Dick, who becomes a [police officer in Blüdhaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bl%C3%BCdhaven#Introduction_to_the_DC_Universe) after becoming Nightwing and was, of course, the original Robin. The hard-luck, orphaned origin and self-professed anger issues I think are mostly from Jason Todd. His deduction of Bruce Wayne/Batman's true identity comes from [Tim Drake, who figures this out as a boy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Drake#Introduction).

Comment: heh, that's pretty interesting!

Answer (score 6):

There’s been one appearance of a "John Blake" in the comics, but only as a kid who gets his report card stolen by the Joker in an early Batman strip, Jack Schiff's 'A Comedy of Tears' (Batman #13, 1942), later recreated for the *256 Pages Super Heroes Coloring Book*. ([source](http://www.batman-online.com/features/2012/7/29/comic-influences-on-the-dark-knight-rises?fb_comment_id=10151123619691215_26982122))

[image: John Blake having his report card stolen by the Joker]
[image: Coloring book page]

Comment: Source? Which strip exactly?

Comment: I know he's the Joker, but what the hell?

Comment: What a jerk joker is?

Comment: great references